# Convert DataTable to List when no Type exists

Tags: c#

I need to convert a DataTable to an untyped List or IEnumerable.  I need something I can loop through.  The problem is it has to be dynamic because only the first 6 columns would be the same for users.  The last 1+ columns are dynamic.  I was able to convert it using the following:

```
 List<dynamic> itemList = ConversionMethods.ConvertDataTableToList<dynamic>(dt);

        public static List<T> ConvertDataTableToList<T>(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<T> data = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            T item = GetItem<T>(row);
            data.Add(item);
        }
        return data;
    }
    private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
    {
        Type temp = typeof(T);
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        try
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                    {
                        if(pro.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? "" : dr[column.ColumnName], null);

                        }
                        else if(pro.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else if(pro.PropertyType == typeof(Double?))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? (Double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(Double))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }

                        else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? (bool?)null : Convert.ToBoolean(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else if(pro.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? null : dr[column.ColumnName], null);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            string msg = ex.Message;

        }
        return obj;

    }
```

But then I was not able to access the properties iterating through the dynamic list like:

```
foreach(var a in itemlist)
{ Name = a.Name}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just loop throw the rows collection on the datatable?  Foreach(var a in conversionMethods.Rows)

Comment: The dataTable = dt.  I need to be able to use the column names and values i.e.(s = a.Name, t= a.Address.  I need to be able to use linq var data = myObject.Where(s=>s.== columnName).ToList();

Comment: If you expect the `Name` property to be listed in VS intellisense, it won't appear there. Properties of `dynamic` type are evaluated at run time. So you can not identify the properties of dynamic type when you are writing the code. But the code will still compile. At runtime it will throw and exception if the property you are trying to use on dynamic type does not exist.

Comment: @Chetan - I wasn't expecting intellisense, but i gives me an error when I try to use known column names.  It says "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'RefNumber''. RefNumber is the key field, but it throws the error no matter which field  (or column name) I use.

Comment: It means that for a particular dynamic object, `Name` property is not available. In your code you are assuming that the object `temp` has that property and then assigning value to it. But when `T` is dynamic there are not properties associated with it... so code inside `foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())` will never be executed... so actually there are no properties associated with the dynamic objects in `itemlist`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It makes plenty of sense.  I get that it didn't work, which is why I am asking for help with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the call in the first line passing in `dynamic`.  As a result, when you take typeof(T).GetProperties(), what is going to be returned?  I would assume nothing, because the dynamic doesn't natively have any properties.  Perhaps you want to use an `ExpandoObject`, assigning the properties as you go along.

Get rid of the "T" generic altogether, and use something like this:

```
private static ExpandoObject GetItem(DataRow dr)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
    try
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
            if(col.DataType == typeof(string))
            {
               obj.Add(col.ColumnName, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? "" : dr[column.ColumnName]);
            }
            ....
         }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
    return obj as ExpandoObject;
}
```

Comment: The above code is throwing an error: "No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments.  I also don't understand what I am replacing the "T" with since you are saying to get rid of it.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff - There is no `T` when you're dealing with `dynamic` objects. `ExpandoObject` is the best you can get. You simply cannot get a compile-type type when you are building your objects at run-time.

Comment: I understand that I cannot use the T, I just don't understand what to replace it with.

Comment: I have a type created for the first 6 fields, it is just the last 3 custom fields that can change.  Is it possible to use the ExpandoObject to add those to the typed object at runtime?

Comment: I fixed the typo causing the lack of compilation.

Comment: GetItem() returns an ExpandoObject, and then you build a List<ExpandoObject>